# Issue upgrade Nativescript angular to angular 9: Running on android

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular9, nativescript-angular

I just upgraded my nativescript angular v8 to v9. I got an error when running

```
tns run android --env.aot
```

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Here is a full StackTrace:

````
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.  
System.err: Calling js method onStart failed
System.err: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/flexbox-layout/flexbox-layout.android.js:14:0)
System.err:     at applyAllNativeSetters(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/properties.js:1065:0)
System.err:     at initNativeView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/properties/properties.js:992:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.onResumeNativeUpdates(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:647:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase._resumeNativeUpdates(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:278:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:232:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.js.View.onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.android.js:249:0)
System.err:     at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:317:75)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:310:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:317:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.loadView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:456:0)
System.err:     at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:234:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js.LayoutBaseCommon.eachChildView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/layouts/layout-base-common.js:125:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js.ViewCommon.eachChild(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:925:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:233:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.js.View.onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.android.js:249:0)
System.err:     at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:317:75)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:310:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:317:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.loadView(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:456:0)
System.err:     at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:234:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.common.js.RadSideDrawer.eachChildView(file: node_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.common.js:149:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js.ViewCommon.eachChild(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view-common.js:925:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:233:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.js.View.onLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view/view.android.js:249:0)
System.err:     at (file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:317:75)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callFunctionWithSuper(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:310:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js.ViewBase.callLoaded(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js:317:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onStart(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/frame.android.js:888:0)
System.err:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/activity.js.NativeScriptActivity.onStart(file: node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/activity.android.js:29:0)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1286)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1173)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1160)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1138)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1134)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onStart(NativeScriptActivity.java:34)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7978)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3472)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I temporally fix this problem by not import anything from @nativescript/core but from sub directory
import Page from @nativescript/core/ui/page than from @nativescript/core